# i2c bus capacitance

Tags: i2c

It is given in philips i2c specification that maximum number of devices connected to the bus is limited by bus capacitance.There is formula specified for pull up resistor but there is no formula to calculate bus capacitance. Then how to calculate bus capacitance?

Comment: [Another thread dealing with I2C bus capacitance.](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/57121/7036)  Just wanted to link it.

Answer (score 7):

Each device on the I2C bus will contribute to the bus capacitance. These values are taken from the device datasheet and added together. Example taken from the first I2C device datasheet I found, the [M24C08](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/stmicroelectronics/5067.pdf):

[image: M24C08]

Remember to include the capacitance of the master device too. Maximum capacitance for the bus is 400pF.

Comment: Don't neglect the capcitance of the cables if the device is remote.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the capacitance of the cables? I am a bit rusty on the subject but I think it depends on the layout of the connections; if so, is there some way to get an approximate value before hands, or is it something one only measures?

Comment: Agreed, this computation appears good if the parts are built to specification and you have the datasheet.  What can we do if there is no datasheet?  Is this something we can measure using an instrument of some kind?

Comment: How to calculate the capacitance contribution of the traces on the PCB?