# I2C pull-up resistors calculation & where to place them

Tags: pic, communication, i2c, pullup

I'm connecting a [PIC18F46K22](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41412F.pdf) (master) to a [PIC18F4620](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39626b.pdf) (slave) using I<sup>2</sup>C. The wire between the devices is ~30cm. I'm using 400kHz without slew rate control. Later on, I'll add another 18F4620 on ~5cm from the master (~35cm from the other slave).

How do I calculate the pull-up resistance needed on both the SCL as the SDA line?

Does it matter where I place the pull-up (near the master, near the slave, both, in the middle, ...)?

Comment: Related: [Is there a correct resistance value for pull-up resistors?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/1852/8159)

Comment: Also relater: [I2C pullup resistor calculations](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/57121/7036)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The pull-ups are generally located near the master device.

[This app note](http://www.edn.com/design/analog/4371297/Design-calculations-for-robust-I2C-communications) goes into some of the calculations. Essentially, the size of the pull-up will be defined by the total bus capacitance and the pull-down capabilities of the devices on the bus:

\$ R_p \ge \dfrac{V_{dd}-V_{OL}}{I_{OL}}\$

and

\$ R_p \le \dfrac{300ns}{0.847298 \times C_{bus}}\$

where \$V_{OL}\$ is the logic low voltage needed, \$I_{OL}\$ is the sinking current, and \$C_{bus}\$ is the bus capacitance.

Of course, once your sample is built, the best thing to do is scope the waveforms and make whatever adjustments are needed.

Answer (score 8):

When the line is pulled low, the driver pin (SCL on master, or SDA on master or slave) supplies current V/R to do that; so if it's a 10k resistor from 5V, the driver will need to sink 0.5 mA. 
A larger resistor means less current is needed, but the line will pull up more slowly (especially on a long line) and this may limit your rate. A smaller resistor pulls up faster, but at some point you'll burn out the driver pin (check the data sheet). 3.3K to 10K is probably fine; if it's 3.3V maybe 2.2K-4.7K

It doesn't matter much where you put them electrically, but near the master is better if the cable might be disconnected; or you could put e.g. a 10k pullup at each end, instead of a single 4k7, which will keep both ends happy when the cable is disconnected.

Generally, for cable lengths to +-20cm, SCL at 100kHz will be happy with 10k. With increasing frequency and/or length, you may go as low as 1k.