# Why does I2C look like this?

Tags: i2c, oscilloscope

[image]
I'm trying to debug an I2C device, and the wave is looking really weird. Why is it curved?

Comment: R-C time. Your trace capacitance is relatively high, or your pull-up resistors are.

Comment: Related: [What happens if I omit the pullup resistors on I2C lines?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/102611/7036)  The O.P. in that thread was using internal pull-ups without knowing it.  Illuminating oscilloscope plots in that thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ICs internally use open drain/collector drivers to actively pull the signal low so you see "fast" fall times.  In contrast, when the drivers are off the line is pulled high through a pull-up resister and consequently you have a longer RC time, and a slower rise.

You don't say what kind of the design this is.  Is it a commercial device or something you've soldered up or perhaps built on a breadboard.  Depending on those things you may want to check the connections and size of resisters being used.  It *might* also be that the ICs you're using require that you enable pull-ups.

Comment: Built in pullups usually are not stiff enough for I2C

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the Arduino, so it seems I need pullup resistors. Thanks!

Comment: Yep you do. Simple 1/4 watt 4k7 ohms is ok. One on each line. The Arduino does have built-in pull-up resistors, you could try to enable those.