# Can I2C work without pull up resistor?

Tags: i2c, protocol

I'm working with nrf51 board, I'm using I2C to communicate with an accelerometer (see the scheme), the communications are successful but I dont see any pull up resistors in the lines `SDA` and `SCL`.

could I2C work without pull-up resistors or is the scheme wrong or does the accelerometer has internal pull up on lines `SDA` and `SCL`[image]

Comment: At leas highlight the lines, so we don't have to break our eyes.. Anyway the PUs can be internal to a chip. I2C can't work without them.

Comment: you can click on the image and zoom, it gives a good look

Comment: And then to parse all of the lines? Thank you. I'll pass.

Comment: @EugeneSh. SDA and SCL are written in red it's really clear

Comment: Don't be so lazy - do the job properly - it's impossible to read the part numbers because the resolution is bad.

Comment: I really dont understand, by cliking on the image, a loop apprear, by cliking again the images become bigger, at least with chrome

Comment: You can't read the part number on the device top right - it connects the the bus and the part number is illegible. Maybe it isn't the temperature sensor but how would I know because I CAN'T READ THE NUMBER!

Comment: @Makhlouf  To be able to work, I2C bus should have pull-ups *somewhere*.  The right way to do it is with discrete resistors.  If you don't find the discrete resistors in your schematic, then the pull-ups are probably in the microcontroller.  Using the pull-ups in the microcontroller is a risky way of doing it, although the I2C bus may still function under favorable conditions.  See [this very similar question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/102616/7036), where the O.P. was running the I2C bus for a long time before realizing that pull-up resistors are missing.

Comment: Short Answer for the question : NO!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Real IIC requires pullup resistors.  Many microcontrollers have optional internal pullup resistors on some pins.  If there is a micro on the bus, and that's usually the case, then it could be switching its pins between pullup and active low.

The pullups in a micro are usually higher resistance than what you'd use for IIC, but for a short bus all on one board when you know the bit rate is low enough, this can be a legitimate thing to do.  I've done it.

Comment: I've done I2C with internal pull-ups too.  But just in case, I had pads for discrete resistors which were DNL (do not load).

Comment: @Nick: That sounds like a good approach.