# I2C data line not having correct voltage levels

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, i2c

I've been working on a project with a EFM8UB1 development board and ATECC508 I2C peripheral.  Everything works fine but I'm having problems with I2C when moving to a PCB.

Here is a trace of the clock

[image]

Here is a trace of data

[image]

My scope isn't very good but notice that the voltage levels for data are incorrect.  It's not fully driving logic 0 low.

Here is an excerpt from my schematic:

[image]

I'm not sure what to do or what could be causing the problem.  Does anyone know of something that could be causing the issue?

[Microcontroller Datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/EFM8UB1_DataSheet.pdf)

[I2C Peripherial Summary](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8923S-CryptoAuth-ATECC508A-Datasheet-Summary.pdf)

### **Update

Turns out the problem was because I mislabeled the pins on a PCB footprint early on in the project.  Thanks for the feedback and suggestions.

Comment: I'm surprised you get anything on the scope. I2C lines need to be pulled-up to VCC. Use around 2-4k resistors.

Comment: You need a pull-up resistor on both SCL and SDA.  Here's a [very similar question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/102611/7036) about the same kind of problem.

Comment: I added the pull up resistors but the problem still persists - please see updated answer

Comment: If 2.2k is better but not enough, then the pull up are still too stiff or there is too much capacitance on the line. I always use 4.7k. 10k as a max. Also check to make sure you didn't enable an internal pull up on your mcu as well.

Comment: I tried 4.7k and 10k but no difference.  Internal pull ups are disabled.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, then you should post the solution as an answer and mark it as such, rather than editing it in to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both SCL and SDA operate as open collector (open drain) outputs. Depending on the speed and of the bus, the resistors should be 10k or lower (usually 4.7k, 2.2k work fine).

The open drain SDA allows to utilise some of the I2C most prominent features. Apart from the obvious like sending data bidirectionally, there is also data acknowledgement (each octet of data is acknowledged by the receiving side), slave detection (acknowledgement of slave address) and bus arbitration (when multiple masters try to access different slave devices, the slave device with the lower address goes first).

But why make the clock as an open collector as well? Well, one of the less known features (and less used) is clock stretching. A slave device may pause a transmission by holding the SCL line low. That stops the clock, but doesn't break the transmission. The slave has time to prepare a response and releases the clock when ready. Funny thing is that the standard does not define the limit of this holdup, so in theory the slave may halt the transmission indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

I2C lines must be pulled to Vcc with external 2k2 resistors. Normal state (when there's no communication) of SDA and SCL is high (voltage near Vcc level). I2C ports in all devices works as open drains (OD): master pull down and release SCL line to send clock signal, slaves and master pull down SDA to send logical '0', and release it to send logical '1'. Your circuit should look like this:
[image: typical I2C bus]

Comment: This helped but the problem still persists - please see updated answer

Comment: @ConorPatrick Are You sure You're connecting I2C device to proper pins of uC and crossbar configuration is correct? Pins 11 and 13 are dedicated to I2C slave interface (I2C0) of EFM8UB, and I2C/SMBus master lines are accessible on any GPIO but first You must configure crossbar!

Comment: thanks this is another good point to check for the EFM8UB1.  Turns out my problem was related to incorrectly labeling pins in a footprint of my PCB but I'm marking this as correct as it's a general solution to the problem i posed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was I mislabeled the pins on a PCB footprint early on in the project.  SCL on microcontroller was connected to a N/C pin and SDA was connected to VCC.  This explains why the SDA pin was not able to fully drive to GND while SCL was correct.

I should be sure to double check footprints and datasheets when transitioning from a dev board to a PCB.

Other answers are good to consider for debugging I2C problems.